# Clean Ember 1.13+ way of knowing if child route is activated

Tags: ember.js

Assume we have an `Article` model as follows:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  author: DS.belongsTo('user'),
  tagline: DS.attr('string'),
  body: DS.attr('string'),
});
```

Assume also that we have a lot of pages, and on every single page we want a ticker that shows the taglines for brand new articles. Since it's on every page, we load all (new) articles at the **application root** level and have a component display them:

```
{{taglines-ticker articles=articles}}
{{output}}
```

That way we can visit any nested page and see the taglines (without adding the component to every page).

The problem is, we **do not want to see** the ticker tagline for an article while it's being viewed, but the root-level `taglines-ticker` has no knowledge of what child route is activated so we cannot simply filter by `params.article_id`. Is there a clean way to pass that information up to the parent route?

**Note:**
This is **not** a duplicate of [how to determine active child route in Ember 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33664374/how-to-determine-active-child-route-in-ember-2), as it does not involve showing active links with `{{link-to}}`

Comment: Typo instead of `Ember.Component` it should be `DS.Model`

Comment: Hah good catch - updated

Comment: You can try using service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to extend the `LinkComponent`, but I ran into several issues and have still not been able to get it to work with `current-when`. Additionally, if several components need to perform the same logic based on child route, they *all* need to extend from `LinkComponent` and perform the same boilerplate stuff just to get it to work.

So, building off of @kumkanillam's comment, I implemented this using a service. It worked perfectly fine, other than the gotcha of having to access the service somewhere in the component in order to observe it.
(See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45190544/observing-a-property-on-a-service-from-a-route-in-emberjs) great question/answer.)

**services/current-article.js**

```
export default Ember.Service.extend({
  setId(articleId) {
    this.set('id', articleId);
  },
  clearId() {
    this.set('id', null);
  },
});
```

**routes/article.js**

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  // Prefer caching currently viewed article ID via service
  // rather than localStorage
  currentArticle: Ember.inject.service('current-article'),

  activate() {
    this._super(arguments);
    this.get('currentArticle').setId(
      this.paramsFor('articles.article').article_id);
  },

  deactivate() {
    this._super(arguments);
    this.get('currentArticle').clearId();
  },

  ... model stuff
});
```

**components/taglines-ticker.js**

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  currentArticle: Ember.inject.service('current-article'),

  didReceiveAttrs() {
    // The most annoying thing about this approach is that it 
    // requires accessing the service to be able to observe it
    this.get('currentArticle');
  },

  filteredArticles: computed('currentArticle.id', function() {
    const current = this.get('currentArticle.id');

    return this.get('articles').filter(a => a.get('id') !== current);
  }),
});
```

---

**UPDATE:**
The `didReceiveAttrs` hook can be eliminated if the service is instead passed through from the controller/parent component.

**controllers/application.js**

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  currentArticle: Ember.inject.service('current-article'),
});
```

**templates/application.hbs**

```
{{taglines-ticker currentArticle=currentArticle}}
  ... model stuff
});
```

**components/taglines-ticker.js**

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  filteredArticles: computed('currentArticle.id', function() {
    const current = this.get('currentArticle.id');

    return this.get('articles').filter(a => a.get('id') !== current);
  }),
});
```

Comment: `currentArticle: Ember.inject.service('current-article')` its equivalent to `currentArticle: Ember.inject.service()`. refer https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.14.0/applications/services/#toc_accessing-services super easy to write it. I always do like this.

Comment: You can even try passing `currentArticle.id` when including `taglines-ticker` component. so that get rid of `didReceiveAttrs` hook code and injection of service in component.

Answer (score 1):

You can still use the `link-to` component to accomplish this, and I think it is an easy way to do it. You aren't sharing your `taglines-ticker` template, but inside it you must have some sort of list for each article. Make a new `tagline-ticker` component that is extended from the `link-to` component, and then use it's `activeClass` and `current-when` properties to hide the tagline when the route is current. It doesn't need to be a link, or look like a link at all.

`tagline-ticker.js`:

```
export default Ember.LinkComponent.extend({
  // div or whatever you want
  tagName: 'div',
  classNames: ['whatever-you-want'],
  // use CSS to make whatever class you put here 'display: none;'
  activeClass: 'hide-ticker',
  // calculate the particular route that should hide this tag in the template
  'current-when': Ember.computed(function() {
    return `articles/${this.get('article.id')}`;
  }),

  init() {
    this._super(arguments);
    // LinkComponents need a params array with at least one element
    this.attrs.params = ['articles.article'];
  },
});
```

`tagline-ticker` being used in `taglines-ticker.hbs`:

```
{{#tagline-ticker}}
  Article name
{{/tagline-ticker}}
```

CSS:

```
.hide-ticker {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Seems like a neat trick, but I haven't been able to get this to apply the `activeClass` when necessary. I updated it to include the extra boilerplate necessary to even get it to not error out.

Comment: Nice edit @kevlarr , and thanks for posting the answer you got to work

Comment: I am still curious about using LinkComponent too, because it _should_ work - I was most likely just not implementing it properly

Answer (score 1):

Ember is adding a proper `router` service in 2.15; this exposes information about the current route as well as some methods that allow for checking the state of the router. There is a polyfill for it on older versions of Ember, which might work for you depending on what version you're currently using:

[Ember Router Service Polyfill](https://github.com/rwjblue/ember-router-service-polyfill)

Based on the RFC that introduced that service, there is an [`isActive` method](https://github.com/emberjs/rfcs/blob/master/text/0095-router-service.md#new-method-checking-for-active-route) that can be used to check if a particular route is currently active. Without knowing the code for `tagline-ticker` it's hard to know exactly how this is used. However, I would imaging that you're iterating over the `articles` passed in, so you could do something like:

```
export default Ember.Component.extends({
  router: Ember.inject.service(),

  articles: undefined,
  filteredArticles: computed('articles', 'router.currentRoute', function() {
    const router = this.get('router');
    return this.get('articles').filter(article => {
       // Return `false` if this particular article is active (YMMV based on your code)
       return !router.isActive('routeForArticle', article); 
    });
  })
});
```

Then, you can iterate over `filteredArticles` in your template instead and you'll only have the ones that are not currently displayed.

Comment: Haven't tried to use the polyfill yet (1.x versions aren't listed as having been tested), but for newer versions of Ember I would think this should **absolutely** be the preferred answer.

Comment: Yeah, they're probably not tested on that old of an Ember version. Since you mentioned 1.13+ I wasn't sure if a 2.X-compatible solution would be appropriate for you.

Comment: I might still try the polyfill honestly, yours is by far the most sane method - I'm glad they made the `router` a public service now.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there a reason you can’t get to Ember 2.8? What version are you on now, 1.13?

Comment: Yep, 1.13... Given the sheer number of deprecations, "old code" (was originally written for an older version), and old packages, we are not sure how much developer time it will take to update to newest Ember, clean out all the errors, and verify 100% feature parity. So it's on deck for some point, we just can't allocate the time right now while launching another app.